# My Xbox 360 turns on, but isn't working

Tags: xbox-360

When I turn on my Xbox 360, I can hear the fan working and the green light in the middle turns on, but there is no video output to the TV. My Xbox has been working perfectly fine until now. The AC adapter's light is orange when the Xbox is off, and turns green when I turn the Xbox on. I am able to open and close the disc tray, but nothing happens when I insert a game.

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: Have you a) made sure your TV is on the correct input, and b) made sure it's not the cable? Also, it would probably be helpful for others to diagnose if you specified whether you're using HDMI or the BigAss™ cable.

Comment: Has it ever suffered from RROD?

Answer (score 1):

First, and easiest, thing to try is resetting the Display settings - per the [Xbox Website](http://support.xbox.com/en-AU/xbox-360/console/image-on-your-tv-is-unclear#b47d0b2237e7471b8ba2698247f339ac), the steps are:

1. Remove any discs from the disc tray.
2. Turn off the console.
3. Turn on the console.
   Note If you are using an Xbox 360 Wireless Controller, turn on the console by using the Guide button on the controller. Make sure that you use the player 1 controller when you do this. The player 1 controller will have the upper-left light illuminated.
4. As the console starts, on the controller, press and hold Y while pulling the right trigger. The display settings are reset to the default settings, and then the console automatically restarts.

If that fails, the HDMI cord may be faulty - if you have any others, try a different cord.